# How to chain Q promise with previous errors on finally()

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I am wondering how to chain errors on Q using finally.

Consider following code

```
function p1() {
    throw new Error("p1 error");
}

function p2() {
    throw new Error("p2 error");
}

function p3() {
    return Q.fcall(p1)
        .finally(function () {
            return Q.fcall(p2);
        }); 
}

p3()
    .done();
```

The Error with message "p1 error" is lost since it was override by Error "p2 error". How can I throw all the errors (or combine the errors)?

Currently, I am working on a socket connection on nodejs. I am using .finally() to close the socket after each connection.

However, errors (eg: authentication error) before .finally() will be overriden by one in .finally() (eg: connection close error). So, I am wondering how to get all errors

Thanks

Comment: this might help: http://rzrsharp.net/2012/10/01/error-isolation-with-promises.html

Comment: Thanks but the link is not quite helpful on my topic. This blog tells you how to catch the errors outside of the promise chain instead of putting error handlers on each then() inside the chain. Effect of this is similar to terminate the chain in the middle by throwing error. However, my case is about the tricky part of finally(). finally() intercept the original errors and replace it with it's new error.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function p3() {
    return Q.fcall(p1)
    .finally(function(p) {
        return Q.fcall(p2).catch(function(e) {
            if (!p.isRejected()) throw e;
            var agg = new Error("multiple errors occured");
            agg[0] = p.inspect().reason;
            agg[1] = e;
            agg.length = 2;
            throw agg;
        });
    }); 
}
```

(based on [Bluebird's `AggregateError`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#aggregateerror))

Of course it is tedious, but I can't imagine something better.